# Why might a Durandal event only trigger some of the subscribed handlers?

Tags: javascript, durandal

I'm working with a Durandal web application that generates an event in response to a certain user action. There are three different javascript files which subscribe to the event. All of the files use the following structure when attaching to the event:

```
app.on('event-name').then(function (eventArgs) {
    // Module specific processing goes here.
}, _this);
```

Using the development tools within Chrome, I can confirm that all of the subscriptions are processed. When the event occurs, only two of the three "then" functions are triggered.

What might be causing this to happen?

Comment: If the module doesn't have a reference to "app" then the subscription would not be created successfully. Another option is the subscription gets disabled somewhere later in the code; look for occurrences of ".off()".

Comment: Are all three of these events tied to the same event-name or are they three separate kinds of events?

Comment: All three are tied to the same event name. That's what's so confusing about it. The subscription being disabled somewhere is a possibility, but if so I haven't found where yet. The first two handlers continue firing. It's only the third one that doesn't.

Comment: Store the result of app.on() to a variable. Then when you break-point the app.on() does the variable successfully contain the subscription object?

Comment: Yes, it does. And having placed that break-point the subscribed function is getting called! Hmmm.... I wonder if there is some sort of weird race condition going on here.